# Clicked on single div of main div container, other divs of main container needs to dont work click event on them.(Jquery)

Tags: jquery

I have 12 divs in main div container.They have different ids respectively.Each div has 6 buttons. When 1st div button is being clicked then dont allow to click on other div's button untill the count equals to 6. When count is equal to 6 then next div is available to click.

Is there any solution in jquery? I have tried out but didn't get how to do that.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: can you post your code what you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This question is highly vague so I'm guessing here, but what you want to do is add the handler for the clicks to the main div itself.

So say your main div has the id `main` and assuming a structure like this:

```
<div id="main">
   <div>
     <button>A</button>
     <button>B</button>
     <!-- ...more buttons -->
   </div>
   <div>
     <button>A</button>
     <!-- ...more buttons<-->
   </div>
   <!-- ...more divs -->
 </div>
```

You could handle click events as they bubble up to main, like:

```
$("#main").on("click", function (e) {
  var data = $(this).data("currentDiv")
    , btnDiv = $(e.target).parent();

  // If no data, this is the first click, prepare
  // the current div data to be stored
  if (!data) {
    data = {el: btnDiv, clicks: 1};
    $(btnDiv).siblings()
      .find("button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  } 

  // If there *is* data and the parent of the clicked
  // button is not the current div, return early.
  else if (!btnDiv.is(data.el)) {
    return;
  }

  // If is the 6th click, clear the current div and 
  // restore the functionality of all buttons    
  else if (5 === data.clicks) {
    $("button", this).removeAttr("disabled");
    data = null;
  }

  // finally, increment click count if we're between
  // 1 and 5 clicks for this div
  else { data.clicks++; }

  $(this).data("currentDiv", data);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JJyW7/1/